# How-to Create A List From An Existant List

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having some issues with an exercise assignment on python:

I need to take a list of items, lets say `lst = [1, 4, 37, 48, 7, 15]`, and create a function that would allow me to extract from this list all numbers that are divisible by one and/or by themselves, creating a new list of items.

`lst = [1, 4, 37, 48, 7, 15]`, z is non negative.

```
def func(lst,z):
    y = []
    z > 0
    for i in lst:
        if (i % z == 0):
            y.append(i)
    return y


print(func(lst,z))
```

Output: [1, 4, 37, 48, 7, 15]

I get the same result list/result.

Comment: cannot understand line `k >= 0`

Comment: If the array contains positive integers, then shouldn't they all be divisible by 1 and themselves (depending on how you handle 1 itself)

Comment: You're not creating/returning a list... you're creating a one-item list each time and just printing it... Make an empty list and `.append` each item, then `return` that list in your function...

Comment: I've just added the .append for the new list y but I get the same result still. Any other suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't every number divisible by itself and 1? That is why your list is the same.

Setting `z=4` yields `[4,48]`, which is every number that is divisible by 1, itself, and 4.